# Why I am getting different GPS point at same location

Tags: android, gps

I am developing an android application to track user movement over a Google map. I am using GPS to pull the user location. It works perfectly fine when I move over road and change my location continuously.

The issue is, when I stop and remain at a point (stops my movement) the GPS keep sending different GPS coordinates.

Please note that I am using GPS in open space and I have used -

Here is the location manager details I am using -

```
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
    criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
    criteria.setBearingAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);
    criteria.setSpeedAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
    String provider = locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,0,0, this);
```

Please let me know, if I am not using it properly.

I have also gone through various blogs and tutorials and learnt that GPS is not perfect at a single location. In that case how I will handle this situation. My aim is to get a single GPS while I am not moving and standing on a single position.

Please let me know.

Thank you !

Comment: ASFAIK GPS for civil use is not accurate at all :) is allways close to that place hehehe.

Comment: A really good gps position has an accuracy of ~2-4 meter. Even if you don't move you will see slight changes  in the position over time since the satellites etc around you are moving.

Comment: @hamilton.lima gps for military use is not better, but safer. You always get different location measures for the same location. That is inherent GPS behavior

Answer (score 0):

RequestLocationUpdates method uses a float value for the third parameter, if you leave it at 0  it will continue to update even if you move a step or two. If you set it to a different number like 50.0 it will update every 50 metres.